# How to geometrically understand that the product of the eigenvalues equals the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

As of now, I'm studying eigenvalues and eigenvectors in Linear Algebra.

I've seen a proof on why the determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues, and in order to further enhance my understanding about eigenvalues, I'd like to understand why this is the case, geometrically speaking.

Personally, I've always found it easier to imagine myself the geometric intuition about certain statements, as it helps me remember them.And, so I'd be really glad if some of you could share some nice geometric interpretation about the statement presented in the title.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometric intuition is as follows:

Suppose the matrix is not defective (i.e., it is $n\times n$ with $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors). Then we can picture the plane, or 3-D space, or N-D space with all these independent eigenvectors drawn out as lines from the origin. The determinant’s geometric intuition is of area: well, if the determinant stretches space along these lines by the eigenvalues, it is very natural that the “amount” the matrix stretches space by in general should be the product of the eigenvalues. If I have some circle, and the matrix stretches it in all the eigen-directions by different eigenvalues, I can represent how much the circle is stretched in total by using the product of stretches.

Another way of putting this: if all of space can be represented as a linear combination of eigenvectors (not always true, but run with it for the sake of intuition), then the matrix’s action on the eigenvectors determines its action on all of space. Thus space is stretched as a combination of stretches along the eigenvectors, giving the product of eigenvalues as the stretch-factor.

Comment: Thank you really, this was a very good explanation for me. I appreciate it :)

Comment: You're welcome @Tanamas. Be advised that this isn't at all rigorous, just a visual pointer to what's going on. I used to picture this as grabbing a sheet (the plane, the space) and spreading it out with my fingers along the eigenvectors in all the different directions, giving a total stretch equivalent to the combination of how much each finger was pushing

Comment: Yes @FShrike, I'll mostly keep it as something visual that can help me to remember the statement. Thank you again :)